# Open an e-mail account from only one particular system?

Tags: email

Is there a way to configure e-mail so that it can only be opened from one particular system? Or from multiple systems having some sort of unique key or particular static IP?

Comment: Kindly see my updated answer. Hope it helps you:)

Comment: did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about opening a single email, then no that is not possible. However if you are talking about a mailserver, then yes this possible. You can use a firewall to restrict access from certan IPs to the mail server and prevent certain clients from accessing your mail server.

Comment: I was talking about single email.So probably its 'NO'

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Lucas said, it is not possible in case you are accessing your inbox. A little bit different scenario is the Gmail two factor authentication where you can specify a trusted computer and only when you access your inbox from that machine, you will bypass the two factor authentication. Any other machine will require two factor authentication.

I guess it is not directly answering your question but may be helpful.

Comment: Yea @Lucas is right but but i was just thinking of making it more secure to break into emails for hackers.
Facebook also provide with same condition where it ask for adding Trusted Computer but I don't think it is that secure as your account can be accessed and it only provide alert.

Sorry wanted to give +1 to both but reputation matters :)

Comment: @user162098 I don't know in case of Facebook but Google won't allow you to login into the account without the code that you get either through SMS or Authenticator app if you login from an untrusted system.

Answer (score 0):

If you send en email encrypted then it can only be opened on a machine where that key is available. Typically the key is associated with the user, but in practice how many users know how to install keys? But the security mechansim follows this paradigm and hence it's usually possible for an authenticated user to extract the key and copy it elsewhere.

The increased use of encryption devices [like this](http://www.startssl.com/?app=6) makes it a more practical solution to your scenario where the user has limited control over the keys stored in the decrypting / encrypting module.

Comment: Yea you are right.Software like PGP and greasemonkey script can be used to encrypt your emails.But I was thinking of restricting account to a system.

Comment: USB dongle + superglue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there are no know email providers who provide this service (yet)!
You brought a really good point, if there is a way to limit access to certain emails through IP's or encryption key!

I would say this could be done, if you manage the email server your self.

Comment: @devBinooh : Thanks and yea you are right.Thing what can be done is to just secure our password via some sort of encryption.